# How to sort by column value in a multi column index dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, multi-level

I have a multi-index dataframe and need to sort the columns by the second level so that the column with 0.1 is first, does anyone know how to do this?

```
            WBAI           ANF           ACEL             
            0.3           0.2           0.1
2018-05-14  17.490000     23.185350     9.861
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) setting `axis=1` (i.e., using columns) and `level=1` (counting starts from 0 so 1 is the second level) as follows:

```py
df = df.sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
```

Result:

```
             ACEL        ANF     WBAI
              0.1        0.2      0.3
2018-05-14  9.861   23.18535    17.49
```